# RcppRoll roll_median na.rm = TRUE gives unexpected results

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I am confused as to why `roll_median(..., na.rm=TRUE)` returns `NA` in the following reprex when there are 11 NA values, but returns a value when there are 10 NA values.

Please note: [The dplyr window function vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/window-functions.html) references using `RcppRoll` for computing rolling aggregates.  As such, I am assuming the usage of `RcppRoll` with `dplyr` for computing rolling aggregates is fairly common and primarily interested in understanding the rationale for the behavior shown below.  Here is a screenshot from `dplyr` window functions vignette.

[image]

First, basic computation with 0 NA values.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(RcppRoll)

mtcars %>%
  transmute(myroll = roll_medianr(mpg, n = nrow(mtcars), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  tail(1)
# myroll
# Volvo 142E   19.2
```

Now, with 10 NA rows, we still get a computed median value.

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(row_number() <= 10, NA, mpg)) %>%
  transmute(myroll = roll_medianr(mpg, n = nrow(mtcars), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  tail(1)
# myroll
# Volvo 142E   15.1
```

However, with 11 NA rows, we get an NA.

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(row_number() <= 11, NA, mpg)) %>%
  transmute(myroll = roll_medianr(mpg, n = nrow(mtcars), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  tail(1)
# myroll
# Volvo 142E     NA
```

Completely ignoring the actual values returns and simply focusing on NA vs . an actual value returned, **why would 10 NAs in the data above return a value, but 11 NAs induce an NA return value**?

Thus far, I am unable to find any explanations for this behavior looking in documentation or searching online.  I am primarily interested in understanding the behavior as I know I can easily use other packages to do accomplish the rolling median, such as `zoo` as shown here.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(zoo))
# 10 NAs using rollapplyr
mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(row_number() <= 10, NA, mpg)) %>%
  transmute(myroll = rollapplyr(mpg, width = nrow(mtcars), FUN = median, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)) %>%
  tail(1)
# myroll
# Volvo 142E  17.55

# 11 NAs using rollapplyr
mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(row_number() <= 11, NA, mpg)) %>%
  transmute(myroll = rollapplyr(mpg, width = nrow(mtcars), FUN = median, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)) %>%
  tail(1)
# myroll
# Volvo 142E   17.3
```

Comment: As there is no Rcpp content here I have removed the `Rcpp` tag.

Comment: Could be an [open issue](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll/issues/26)

Comment: @Waldi thanks for the link.  That specific issue is open and untouched since 2017 and looking further it appears this package is not really maintained anymore, per [this issue](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll/issues/41)

Comment: Which version of RcppRoll do you use? I can't reproduce this using the latest CRAN version (0.3.0), even get the same results as with rollapplyr. Further, I think the issue has been addressed [here](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll/commit/2c8e09eb7283524641e31f1bfa49c1de90a11bbf).

Comment: @MartinC.Arnold I'm using the latest CRAN version (0.3.0) which was published to CRAN on June 2018, well before the fixed issue you linked from July 2021.  It appears the latest version in github that includes the fix is also listed as version 0.3.0 [source](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll/blame/master/DESCRIPTION).  So my guess is you have the github version, but the CRAN version does not include the fix, and both have the same verson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with `0.3.0` version from CRAN.
However, as mentionned in comments, the error has been corrected on GitHub.

You could download [RcppRoll-master](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll/archive/refs/heads/master.zip) from GitHub and install anew the package (for this you'll need Rtools):

```
Rcmd.exe INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source RcppRoll-master
```

After this, it works as expected:

```
library(RcppRoll)
mtcars %>%
   transmute(myroll = roll_medianr(mpg, n = nrow(mtcars), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   tail(1)

           myroll
Volvo 142E   19.2
```

The version number stays the same:

```
packageVersion('RcppRoll')
[1] ‘0.3.0’
```

Looks like the last corrections haven't been yet pushed to CRAN with an new version number.